# Using a python 2.6 package in python 3.10

Tags: python, python-2.6

## Background

I want to learn python through creating an isometric RPG computer game. To make it a little more fun at the start, I thought I would instead of starting from scratch, alter another very basic isometric RPG and bit by bit make it my own*. I thought [this game](https://www.pygame.org/project/294) would be a suitable candidate. The problem is that it was made with python 2.6. I have already converted all the code to python 3, but when starting the debug process, I encountered the issue that the package `ocempgui` does not exist anymore. I cannot seem to install it with either `pip` or `conda`, because it is not in the repositories.

## Question

Is there any way that I can use the `ocempgui` package in python 3? [(link)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj664rLopf-AhXI-KQKHVg_DVIQFnoECA8QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pygame.org%2Fproject-OcempGUI-125-.html&usg=AOvVaw2bmBMBlYc6-1xmrAZnKD-6)

## PS

If someone knows another basic isometric RPG written in python 3, please let me know.

*Some of you might say that it is better to start from scratch, but I think it is more important to stay motivated to work on it.

Comment: https://ocemp.sourceforge.net/index.html last release 2009...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well unless you're going to find the source code for that library `ocempgui` and rebuild it to run in your current version of python you're out of luck.  Library versioning is a large portion of working in any language python included.

Comment: Thank you for ripping off the band-aid ;)

Answer (score 1):

Finding the sources of *ocempgui* [is easy](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ocemp/files/ocempgui/), but since it had seen no updates since 2008(!), you'll have to port it to modern Python versions **and** modern Pygame versions, which is likely to be even more challenging (provided there's no more up-to-date forks).  If I were you, I would instead look into replacing *ocempgui* with pure *Pygame*, I'd expect it to grow way more comprehensive in 15 years =)